# redirect file to an url for streaming

Tags: file, url, audio, stream

I am setting up my hi-fi to stream music from my PC. The hi-fi can see all of the files in my music folder, but I want to be able to stream across the audio I am currently playing. The hi-fi however does not have support for this.

So I've found a .dll that wraps directsound and offers it streaming as a continuous mp3 file on my PC from localhost:8124

I want to make a file in my music folder that will point to this (i.e. audio.mp3). So when my hi-fi streams audio.mp3 and plays it, it will actually receive the contents from localhost:8124.

I've tried using symbolic links, but they don't seem to allow me to do this.

Finally I am running Windows 7.

Can I do this? and if so how?

Comment: You might try your question on SuperUser.com or HowToGeek.com.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that.  You can't create something that looks like a file, but actually streams the content from some other location.

If your hi-fi doesn't support streaming, there's no solution.  If it does support streaming, you'll need to find a way to support the streaming protocol it does handle.